# SSD read errors in non-mounted partitions: can I fix them?

Tags: ssd, windows

I have a fairly new 500 GB Samsung SSD mounted in a 7 year old high-powered custom Windows 10 desktop. The desktop is still powerful enough for what I do on it (hobby programming, personal finance, long-running data science dabbles), and I have other machines, so I haven't looked to replace it.

The SSD has 3 partitions: System Reserved, C:, and Recovery:
[image: Image from Windows 10 Disk Manager]

My backup software (Acronis) is set to back up all drive partitions every morning. It is experiencing read failures on one of them (I think "System Reserved", but the error doesn't say.)

The advice I've read says to scan this disk for block errors, and that maybe they'd be recoverable.  However, all the utilities I've tried check only the C: partition. I'm pretty sure that's NOT the partition experiencing the error.

(Samsung's Magician doesn't do any on-demand checking, and only reports on the C: partition, but it does tell me that the SMART data checks out OK.)

I did, in desperation, temporarily assign letters to the other two partitions, and scan them using `chkdsk`, but no errors were reported.

Shutting the machine off and letting it rest before booting generally makes the problem go away for a bit, but long-running jobs mean that I can't reboot every day.

So:

1. Is there a way -- a handy tool -- to identify and fix errors in a non-mounted SSD partition?
2. Given that a rest seems to fix it, is this most likely a heat problem? I built this machine myself, but from someone else's spec, and their CPU cooler recommendation turned out to be inadequate. It may be that the higher-powered fan I now have, plus the graphics card fans, are still not providing enough cooling for the whole case.
3. Should I give up on this SSD, and buy a new one, on the grounds that this one is probably going to fail anyway?  (It's only a few years old.)